# Google Cloud KMS - Encrypting SSH key (id_rsa)

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-kms

I am currently following https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/access-private-github-repos but I am stuck and I am not sure to understand.

In fact I have done the following:

```
MBP-de-Emixam23:security-service emixam23$ gcloud kms keyrings create id_rsa --location=global
MBP-de-Emixam23:security-service emixam23$ gcloud kms keys create gitlab-key --location=global --keyring=id_rsa --purpose=encryption
MBP-de-Emixam23:security-service emixam23$ gcloud kms encrypt --plaintext-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa --ciphertext-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa.enc --location=global --keyring=id_rsa --key=gitlab-key
ERROR: (gcloud.kms.encrypt) Failed to read plaintext file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: Unable to read file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
MBP-de-Emixam23:security-service emixam23$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
.....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-------
```

Can someone tell to me where the `gcloud kms` is looking for? I actually need it for google cloud build trigger purpose

Thanks !

## Edit 1 - Verbosity added for John's comment

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.kms.encrypt] with arguments: [--ciphertext-file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.enc", --key: "gitlab-key", --keyring: "id_rsa", --location: "global", --plaintext-file: "~/.ssh/id_rsa", --verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: (gcloud.kms.encrypt) Failed to read plaintext file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: Unable to read file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emixam23/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 984, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/emixam23/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 798, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/emixam23/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/kms/encrypt.py", line 90, in Run
    args.plaintext_file, e))
BadFileException: Failed to read plaintext file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: Unable to read file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
ERROR: (gcloud.kms.encrypt) Failed to read plaintext file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: Unable to read file [~/.ssh/id_rsa]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

Comment: Turn on `gcloud` debugging. `--verbosity=debug`

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Have you tried expanding the `~` into the path to the directory? I think it's possible that the API that gcloud uses doesn't understand the `~` shell expansion

Comment: It makes me crazy to lose so much of time just on this... Thanks @TimDierks, that was the issue. You can post an answer and I will validate it tomorrow! Thanks John as well

Comment: How did you create the file `id_rsa`? That is the input file. Your jobs are running in a container. Do not rely upon a `user` context such as `~`. Use full pathnames and not shell paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the villain here is tilde expansion. This is usually done by the shell, but (like everything else), there are complications.

Tilde expansion is only done at the start of words in sh and bash. So if you pass `--plaintext-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it works, because the shell parses the second parameter as a word of its own and expands the leading `~`. If you pass `--plaintext-file=~/.ssh/id_rsa`, the lack of whitespace means the shell sees everything as a single token and doesn't expand the `~`. If gcloud expanded the leading `~` itself after parsing out the argument, you'd be fine (but it apparently does not).

Any time you see an error message printed with the `~` in the filename, be suspicious: if the shell had expanded the ~, you'd be seeing the full path that the shell would have passed to the binary, not the raw `~`.

Some shells support expansion within parameters after `=`; for example, `zsh` has a config parameter, `MAGIC_EQUAL_SUBST` which  turns this behavior on. `bash` will also do this when not in POSIX mode if the parameter looks like a variable assignment, but the leading `--` means this doesn't look like a variable assignment to bash.

While gcloud supports either `--flag value` or `--flag=value` grammar, if you needed the `--flag=value` structure, you could use `${HOME}` instead of `~` to get similar expansion. (I won't go into all the details of how these may vary, yay edge cases.)

Thanks for using Cloud KMS!

Answer (score 2):

As the error output indicates, the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` does not exist. This could be for a few reasons.

In most shells (sh, bash, zsh), `~` expands to the current user's home directory. The *shell* does this expansion, usually based off of `$HOME` of the user in which you're running the command. If you invoke the command with `sudo`, for example, `~` will resolve to root's home, not your home. From the command output, it appears that `~` is being literally sent to gcloud, but gcloud expects the shell to resolve it first.

If you're using a different shell, it's possible that `~` is not supported. This seems most likely given your `cat` command works.

Another possibility is that the `=` is causing your shell not to parse the `~`. I tried to reproduce your issue, but I cannot. Nonetheless, it would be helpful to try the following command (I've removed the optional `=` for arguments):

```sh
gcloud kms encrypt \
  --plaintext-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  --ciphertext-file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.enc \
  --location global \
  --keyring id_rsa \
  --key gitlab-key
```

It's very important that you do not surround the filepaths with quotes, because then they will be interpreted literally instead of resolved by the shell.

As a last resort, you can force the shell to expand the directory like this:

```sh
gcloud kms encrypt \
  --plaintext-file "$(cd ~/.ssh && pwd)/id_rsa" \
  --ciphertext-file "$(cd ~/.ssh && pwd)/id_rsa.enc" \
  --location global \
  --keyring id_rsa \
  --key gitlab-key
```